# Node JS function not being executed. What could be the reason?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

I want to capture a payment and create a transfer immediately on a payment using Firebase Cloud Functions. The capture is happening correctly but the transfer is not being executed. What could be the reason?

Docs for reference: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node/blob/master/examples/index.js

The following is the source code for my Firebase Cloud Function:

```
   exports.CapturePayment = functions.database.ref('payment_id').onWrite((event) => {

  const payment_id = event.data.val();

  // Capture a particular payment
rzp.payments.capture(payment_id, 100000).then((data) => {

  return event.data.ref.child('status').set(data);
  console.log(data);

  // Create transfers on a payment
rzp.payments.transfer(payment_id, {
  transfers: [
    {
      account: 'acc_aldsfkas123123adsf',
      amount: 100,
      currency: 'INR'
    }
  ]
}).then((data) => {
  var db = admin.database();
  var ref = db.ref("transfer");
  return ref.update("Success");
   console.log(data)

}).catch((error) => {
  var db = admin.database();
  var ref = db.ref("transfer");
  return ref.update("Failure");
   console.error(error)
})

  // success
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);

  // error
})

});
```

Comment: You are returning before doing the transfer. That code will never run.

Comment: The first line in `rzp.payments.capture()` is a return. Nothing else gets executed. Is that just a typo?

Comment: So how should I change the code?

Comment: No, the return returns a json object with a lot of data. Check this out: https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/v1paymentsidcapture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the data in your initial call, but also do the transfer, just change it to the following:

```
// Capture a particular payment
rzp.payments.capture(payment_id, 100000).then((data) => {
  const ret = event.data.ref.child('status').set(data);
  console.log(data)

  // Create transfers on a payment
  rzp.payments.transfer(payment_id, {
    transfers: [
      {
        account: 'acc_aldsfkas123123adsf',
        amount: 100,
        currency: 'INR'
      }
    ]
  })

  return ret
})
```

The problem is that you were using `return` before running your transfer function. Once a `return` is hit, the code following it will never be run. By storing your desired return in a variable, you can do other work, and then return it.

Alternatively, you could run the code in a different order, as it looks like the two calls don't depend on each other.

---

Really though, you should be breaking all your async work out into single serving, and understandable functions that can be chained together for better readability. For example, your chain might look like this:

```
capturePayment(payment_id, 100000)
  .then(updateDB)
  .then(transfer)
  .then(data => console.log('success'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Then all you have to ensure is that each of your chaining functions takes a single argument, that can be passed from the result of the previous.

Comment: I know this is beyond the scope of the question, but it's hard to look at the async `set()` function being called like that and proceeding with a transfer without over waiting to see if `set()` was successful. It seems like `rzp.payments.transfer()` should be called after `set()`'s promise resolves..

Comment: I agree. All their async work should be extracted into single serve functions. I was just trying the simplest alteration to resolve the return issue.

Comment: @Mark_M Without rewriting all their code, I added some extra stuff that might point them in a better direction.

Answer (score 1):

You have a return statement in the first line of the function in your first then method call. All the code that comes after that is not executed, hence no transfer is being executed.

```
rzp.payments.capture(payment_id, 100000).then((data) => {

  return event.data.ref.child('status').set(data);

  /* NO CODE AFTER THE RETURN STATEMENT IS EXECUTED */
  console.log(data);

  // Create transfers on a payment
  rzp.payments.transfer(payment_id, {
```

Comment: This points out the problem but the other solution was more comprehensive. Thanks anyways!